# Qual a tag apropriada para uma pergunta relacionada a tasks ants

Tags: debate

A pergunta [Alterar linhas de código dentro de arquivos com Apache Ant](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27414/alterar-linhas-de-c%C3%B3digo-dentro-de-arquivos-com-apache-ant)
possui as tags `java` e `apache` porém eu entendo que se trata de uma pergunta que não está diretamente relacionada a estes tópicos mas sim algo que deveria ser ligado primariamente a uma tag como `ant`,`ant-tasks` ou `build`.

Qual a tag apropriada (deveria ser criada?) para uma pergunta relacionada a tasks ants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta editar a pergunta e inserir a tag `ant`.
No stackoverflow a tag [ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant) é utilizada.